# Drop Column in DataFrame, then write output

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to drop a column in a DataFrame using pandas. This code is not working and I really don't know why. It's simple and quick. What am I missing?

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
for col in df.columns.values:
    if input('Delete ' + col + '? yes/no') == 'yes':
        df.drop([col], axis=1)

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: "Is not working" doesn't really help, please provide information on what is your expected result and what is the actual result. Does an error message pop up?

Comment: df.drop does not modify the dataframe in place. You can reassign `df = df.drop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Inplace' option for 'Drop' as below :

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
for col in df.columns.values:
   if input('Delete ' + col + '? yes/no') == 'yes':
      df.drop([col], axis = 1, inplace = TRUE)

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Works like this. Thanks to @julian.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
for col in df.columns.values:
    if input('Delete ' + col + '? yes/no') == 'yes':
        df = df.drop([col], axis=1)

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```